# Passing list of compound keys as parammeter to query?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Our legacy system has table `T` with compound key -two columns `A` and `B`, I need to search for rows, that match my criteria, that `A == x AND B == y`.

But for set of touples of `(x,y)` like `{(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)}`

If I do `X = {x1,x2x3}` and `Y = {y1,y2,y3}`

```
select A,B,value from T where A in (X) and B in (Y)
```

My result might contain row `x1, y2, valueN`, but that is not correct

I don't have upper bound for count of touples, and I need to pass it as parameters from Java code.

My server is MS SQL 2008

Looks like Table Valued Parameter could be the answer, but it's not yet supported by JDBC driver

(hope this is clear enough)

Answer (score 0):

One hack you can use is to convert values to strings and concatenate them

Comment: Question is how to do that without hack, but thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

Use a statement that checks the combinations:

```
SELECT A, B, value FROM T WHERE A = X1 AND B = Y1 OR A = X2 AND B = Y2
```

Use a prepared statement and query each combination individually (note: using Java 7 try-with-resources here)

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT A, B, value FROM T WHERE A = X1 AND B = Y1")) {
  for (Tuple tuple : tuples) {
    pstmt.setObject(1, tuple.X);
    pstmt.setObject(2, tuple.Y);
    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
      while (rs.next()) {
        // process however you like
      }
    }
  }
}
```